# How can I show that a problem is not $NP$

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, reductions, np-hard

Consider the following image:

[image]

The problem is: *can we cover the bigger rectangle with small rectangles such that no two rectangles overlap and no gap opens up?* Prove that this problem is $NP-Hard$.

I know that to prove that it is $NP-hard$, I must reduce a $NPC$ problem to it.

However, I guess that the problem is not $NP$, right? For example, even if we have a "**Yes**" answer for the items above, how can we fit the small rectangles into the big rectangle in polynomial time?

For the above problem, the answer can *includes* the placement of small rectangles in the bigger rectangle. So, verifying it is easy, and the problem is $NP$.

Suppose, the question was: *is there any subset of rectangles that cover the bigger rectangle so no two rectangles overlap and no gap opens up?*

Then, what would be the shape of a certificate? Would it be verifiable in polynomial time? Would it be just a subset of items, or their placements too?

What if it was an optimization problem requesting *a subset of items that cover the largest area of the bigger rectangle*? Then, we had to check other answers to see that the certificate is the optimum one, and that would make the problem non-**NP**, right?

How a certificate is defined in such cases, and what is its role in categorizing a problem as $NP$ or non-$NP$?!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85503/discussion-between-ahmad-and-yuval-filmus).

Answer (score 2):

The only result that I am aware of (assuming your problem is computable) is the [time hierarchy theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_hierarchy_theorem), which implies that $NP\neq NEXPTIME$. If you have a problem that is $NEXPTIME$-hard and show that that problem reduces to your problem, you've shown your problem isn't in $NP$. Since $NEXPTIME\subseteq EXPSPACE$, an $EXPSPACE$-hard problem would work as well.

Your problem is in $NP$, however.

Comment: Thank you! you may look at my update too...

Comment: @Ahmad the same certificate would apply for positive cases.